# What is the difference between `UnitRange` and `Array`?

Tags: julia

I have two versions of code that seem to do the same thing:

```
sum = 0
for x in 1:100
    sum += x
end
```

```
sum = 0
for x in collect(1:100)
    sum += x
end
```

Is there a practical difference between the two approaches?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Julia, `1:100` returns a particular struct called `UnitRange` that looks like this:

```
julia> dump(1:100)
UnitRange{Int64}
  start: Int64 1
  stop: Int64 100
```

This is a very compact struct to represent ranges with step 1 and arbitrary (finite) size.  `UnitRange` is subtype of `AbstractRange`, a type to represent ranges with arbitrary step, subtype of `AbstractVector`.

The instances of `UnitRange` dynamically compute their elements whenever the you use `getindex` (or the syntactic sugar `vector[index]`).  For example, with `@less (1:100)[3]` you can see this method:

```
function getindex(v::UnitRange{T}, i::Integer) where {T<:OverflowSafe}
    @_inline_meta
    val = v.start + (i - 1)
    @boundscheck _in_unit_range(v, val, i) || throw_boundserror(v, i)
    val % T
end
```

This is returning the `i`-th element of the vector by adding `i - 1` to the first element (`start`) of the range.  Some functions have optimised methods with `UnitRange`, or more generally with `AbstractRange`.  For instance, with `@less sum(1:100)` you can see the following

```
function sum(r::AbstractRange{<:Real})
    l = length(r)
    # note that a little care is required to avoid overflow in l*(l-1)/2
    return l * first(r) + (iseven(l) ? (step(r) * (l-1)) * (l>>1)
                                     : (step(r) * l) * ((l-1)>>1))
end
```

This method uses the [formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Arithmetic_progression&oldid=903559997#Sum), which is extremely efficient as it's evaluated in a time independent of the size of the vector.

On the other hand, `collect(1:100)` returns a plain `Vector` with one hundred elements 1, 2, 3, ..., 100.  The main difference with `UnitRange` (or other types of `AbstractRange`) is that `getindex(vector::Vector, i)` (or `vector[i]`, with `vector::Vector`) doesn't do any computation but simply accesses the `i`-th element of the vector.  The downside of a `Vector` over a `UnitRange` is that generally speaking there aren't efficient methods when working with them as the elements of this container are completely arbitrary, while `UnitRange` represents a set of numbers with peculiar properties (sorted, constant step, etc...).

If you compare the performance of methods for which `UnitRange` has super-efficient implementations, this type will win hands down (note the use of interpolation of variables with `$(...)` when using macros from `BenchmarkTools`):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime sum($(1:1000_000))
  0.012 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
500000500000

julia> @btime sum($(collect(1:1000_000)))
  229.979 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
500000500000
```

Remember that `UnitRange` comes with the cost of dynamically computing the elements every time you access them with `getindex`.  Consider for example this function:

```
function test(vec)
    sum = zero(eltype(vec))
    for idx in eachindex(vec)
        sum += vec[idx]
    end
    return sum
end
```

Let's benchmark it with a `UnitRange` and a plain `Vector`:

```
julia> @btime test($(1:1000_000))
  812.673 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
500000500000

julia> @btime test($(collect(1:1000_000)))
  522.828 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
500000500000
```

In this case the function calling the plain array is faster than the one with a `UnitRange` because it doesn't have to dynamically compute 1 million elements.

Of course, in these toy examples it'd be more sensible to iterate over all elements of `vec` rather than its indices, but in real world cases a situation like these may be more sensible.  This last example, however, shows that a `UnitRange` is not necessarily more efficient than a plain array, especially if you need to dynamically compute all of its elements.  `UnitRange`s are more efficient when you can take advantage of specialised methods (like `sum`) for which the operation can be performed in constant time.

As a file remark, note that if you originally have a `UnitRange` it's not necessarily a good idea to convert it to a plain `Vector` to get good performance, especially if you're going to use it only once or very few times, as the conversion to `Vector` involves itself the dynamic computation of all elements of the range and the allocation of the necessary memory:

```
julia> @btime collect($(1:1000_000));
  422.435 μs (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)

julia> @btime test(collect($(1:1000_000)))
  882.866 μs (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
500000500000
```